# regexp.FindSubmatch with hex character codes

Tags: regex, go

I cannot regexp.FindSubmatch in certain simple cases. For example, following code works properly:

```
assigned := regexp.MustCompile(`\x7f`)
group := assigned.FindSubmatch([]byte{0x7f})
fmt.Println(group)
```

([in playground it prints [[127]]](http://play.golang.org/p/RPNVwDPC74))

But if I change byte to 0x80 it [does not work](http://play.golang.org/p/jc1Ebjpad_). Why?

Comment: `regexp` operates on UTF-8 encoded strings; `{0x80}` is not a valid UTF-8 encoded string.

Comment: Sad. I move my code from PowerShell where I had no such restriction for binary data.

Comment: [`bytes.Contains`](https://godoc.org/bytes#Contains) may work for you instead.

Comment: Thanks, but  know. It is not enough.

Comment: @algebrain _"It is not enough"_ You haven't stated your original intent. `bytes.Contains` solves the problem you stated. If you want help for your original problem, maybe you should reveal it.

Comment: Sure, my original problem is following: I need to check many different regular expressions for non-utf8 binary samples.

Comment: @algebrain You could convert your input byte sequence to its hexadecimal representation (which has a valid utf-8 encoding) and define your regexp (or convert your existing ones) to operate on the hex input string.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned [in the package documentation](http://golang.org/pkg/regexp/#pkg-overview):

> All characters are UTF-8-encoded code points.

So the regular expression `\x80` does not match the byte value `0x80`, but rather the UTF-8 representation of the character `U+0080`.  This is evident if we change your test program to:

```
func main() {
    assigned := regexp.MustCompile(`\x80`)
    group := assigned.FindSubmatch([]byte{1, 2, 3, 0xc2, 0x80})
    fmt.Println(group)
}
```

We now get a match for the two byte sequence `[[194 128]]`, which represents that character in question.

There is no way to switch the `regexp` package into a binary mode, so you will either need to convert your inputs to valid UTF-8, or use a different package to match your data.

Comment: Thanks. I think this restriction is proper in case of FindStringSubmatch, but for FindSubmatch it is strange and inconvenient.